# recaptcha v2 for flutter web - navigate to other screen after success

Tags: html, flutter, dart, recaptcha, flutter-web

Im currently want to implement recaptcha v2 into my flutter web project, this what my progress looks like

```
recaptcha.html

<html>
 <head>
  <title>reCAPTCHA</title>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer> 
  </script>
</head>
<body style='background-color: rgb(255, 191, 0);'>
  <div style='height: 30px;'></div>
  <form action="?" method="POST">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" 
      data-sitekey="MY_SITEKEY"
      data-callback="captchaCallback"></div>
  </form>
  <script>
    function captchaCallback(response){
      //console.log(response);
      alert(response);
      if(typeof Captcha!=="undefined"){
        Captcha.postMessage(response);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

inside my dart code

```
@override
void initState() {
  PlatformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
  createdViewId,
  (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
    ..style.height = '100%'
    ..style.width = '100%'
    ..src = 'assets/html/recaptcha.html'
    ..style.border = 'none',
);}
```

And then i call the captcha itself

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: HtmlElementView(
            viewType: createdViewId,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Everything looks fine, however my question is that the callback is at the recaptcha.html, so how do i make it that once the captcha is success, my system will navigate to the next page ?

Ps - don't give any suggestion for using https://pub.dev/packages/g_recaptcha_v3 or any other recaptcha version since my plan is to use only V2 and for Flutter Web

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this line on your `recaptcha.html` file inside `captchaCallback(response)` function:

```
window.parent.postMessage(response, "*");
```

You should add this line after `registerViewFactory` on your `initState`:

```
html.window.onMessage.listen((msg) {
  print(msg.data);
});
```

The `msg.data` is your captcha token. And you can do whatever you want inside this listener, like navigating to next page or enabling a submit form button.